# Putting variable into html text box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a script that pulls data from the SQL database, stores the data into variables. Now I need to take that data and put them into HTML forms (textboxes?) so they can edit them, and then I will run a UPDATE query to update.

```
  ' Create a DataReader and execute the command
  objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader

  While objDR.Read()
  sale_id = objDR(0)
  cust_id = objDR(1)
  agent_id = objDR(2)
  saledate = objDR(3)
  actualamount = objDR(4)
  contractid = objDR(5)
  homeid = objDR(6)
  End While

  strSuccess.Text = "<h2>Sale ID #" & agent_id & " and " & actualamount & "</h2>"
  strSuccess.Visible = "True"

 ' Close all objects
  objDR.Close
  objCmd.Dispose
  objDBConn.Close

End Sub
</script>
<title>CUSTOMERS table</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Oracle sales table contents</h2>
<asp:label id="strSuccess" runat="server" />

Sale Amount: <input TYPE="text" NAME="saledate">

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to take 'saledate' and put it into the sale amount form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your value in vb and add a **asp:TextBox** control instead of **html** control in your Sale Amount form.
You can do it by change your code in this way：

```
 ' Create a DataReader and execute the command
  objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader

  While objDR.Read()
  sale_id = objDR(0)
  cust_id = objDR(1)
  agent_id = objDR(2)
  saledate = objDR(3)
  actualamount = objDR(4)
  contractid = objDR(5)
  homeid = objDR(6)
  End While

  strSuccess.Text = "<h2>Sale ID #" & agent_id & " and " & actualamount & "</h2>"
  strSuccess.Visible = "True"
  txtsaledate.Text = saledate  'Set value here 

 ' Close all objects
  objDR.Close
  objCmd.Dispose
  objDBConn.Close

End Sub
</script>
<title>CUSTOMERS table</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm" runat="server">
<center>
<h2>Oracle sales table contents</h2>
<asp:label id="strSuccess" runat="server" />

Sale Amount: <asp:TextBox ID="txtsaledate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a error "Text is not a member of String" on the line saledate.Text = saledate